# How to debug "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first" in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have written code to filter data from database(filtering is done by two dropdownlists and between 2 dates). I am getting an error

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

[this is my front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvsvf.png)

```
public partial class data : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con;

    string constring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
    }

    protected void btnshow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                       
        if ((ddldept.SelectedValue == "all") && (ddldesig.SelectedValue!="all") )
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            con.Open();
            string desig = ddldesig.SelectedValue;
            DateTime mydate;
            mydate = Convert.ToDateTime(tbfrom.Text);
            string from = Convert.ToString(mydate);
            mydate = Convert.ToDateTime(tbto.Text);
            string to = Convert.ToString(mydate);
            SqlCommand cmddeptall = new SqlCommand("select * from registration where Department IN('Computer Science Engineering','Mechanical Engineering','Electrical And Electronics','Electronics And Communication','Civil Engineering','Science And Humanity') AND PostAppliedFor='"+desig+"' AND (RegisteredDate BETWEEN '"+from+"' AND '"+to+"')",con);
            cmddeptall.ExecuteReader();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmddeptall);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "registration");
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["registration"];
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }

        else if ((ddldept.SelectedValue == "all") && (ddldesig.SelectedValue == "all"))
        {
            SqlConnection con;

            string constring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            try
            {
                con.Open();

                DateTime mydate;
                mydate = Convert.ToDateTime(tbfrom.Text);
                string from = Convert.ToString(mydate);
                mydate = Convert.ToDateTime(tbto.Text);
                string to = Convert.ToString(mydate);
                string query = "select * from registration where Department IN('Computer Science Engineering','Mechanical Engineering','Electrical And Electronics','Electronics And Communication','Civil Engineering','Science And Humanity') AND PostAppliedFor IN('Principal','Professor','Associate Professor','Assistant Professor','Placement Officer','SoftSkills Trainer','Administrative Officer','Office Superintendent','Lab Technician') AND (RegisteredDate BETWEEN  '" + from + "' AND '" + to + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.ExecuteReader();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "registration");
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();


                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }     

        }
        else if ((ddldept.SelectedValue != "all") && (ddldesig.SelectedValue != "all"))
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            con.Open();
            string desig = ddldesig.SelectedValue;
            string dept = ddldept.SelectedValue;
            DateTime mydate;
            mydate = Convert.ToDateTime(tbfrom.Text);
            string from = Convert.ToString(mydate);
            mydate = Convert.ToDateTime(tbto.Text);
            string to = Convert.ToString(mydate);
            SqlCommand cmddeptall = new SqlCommand("select * from registration where Department='"+dept+"' AND PostAppliedFor='"+desig+"' AND (RegisteredDate BETWEEN '" + from + "' AND '" + to + "')", con);
            cmddeptall.ExecuteReader();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmddeptall);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "registration");
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["registration"];
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
        con.Close
    }
```

Comment: When you ask a question, please narrow down your code to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than posting all of your code. And say which line the error occurs on.

Comment: The error you got, pretty much tells you what is wrong

Comment: my error was sort out but i am not able to get exact result for filteration.. may be its because of calander text box date format..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you are not **disposing** any objects properly. You should make database calls as mentioned below:

```
var ds = new DataSet();
if ((ddldept.SelectedValue == "all") && (ddldesig.SelectedValue != "all"))
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        con.Open();
        string desig = ddldesig.SelectedValue;
        DateTime mydate;
        mydate = Convert.ToDateTime(tbfrom.Text);
        string from = Convert.ToString(mydate);
        mydate = Convert.ToDateTime(tbto.Text);
        string to = Convert.ToString(mydate);
        using (var cmddeptall = new SqlCommand("select * from registration where Department IN('Computer Science Engineering','Mechanical Engineering','Electrical And Electronics','Electronics And Communication','Civil Engineering','Science And Humanity') AND PostAppliedFor='" + desig + "' AND (RegisteredDate BETWEEN '" + from + "' AND '" + to + "')", con))
        {
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmddeptall))
            {
                da.Fill(ds, "registration");
            }
        }
    }
}
else if ((ddldept.SelectedValue == "all") && (ddldesig.SelectedValue == "all"))
{
    // Code Here
}
else if ((ddldept.SelectedValue != "all") && (ddldesig.SelectedValue != "all"))
{
    // Code Here
}
```

**Note:** Moreover, I would suggest you to create separate function to call database and retrieve dataset based on query you have made. There is no need of writing same code again and again.

Comment: thank u so much it helped me alot...but i dont get result for the filteration... i have added  under                                                                                                   da.Fill(ds,"registration");                                                                                                                   GridView1.DataSourceID = String.Empty;
                        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                        GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: i am not able to get the result between two dates filteration(textbox having calender).. results for filteration with dropdownlist is working

Comment: i am having problem with the date format.. how to format it?

Comment: @SufiaBano: There must be some problem with your query. Copy the database query and try to execute on SQL Server and check whats going wrong with your query.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to execute the reader when you use the command in the [`SqlDataAdapter.Constructor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awzk4kc1(v=vs.110).aspx), that's done implicitly at `da.Fill`. So remove the first line:

```
cmddeptall.ExecuteReader();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmddeptall);
```